# Bundle FOSOAuthServerBundle setup error

Tags: symfony, installation, bundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I have installed FOSOauthServerBundle but it seems that the config is wrong with the csrf_provider that I do not know how to resolve it, as I copied the code from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md 
When I execute composer update I have this error

```
[RuntimeException]
      An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationExcept
      ion] Unrecognized option "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login"
```

When I go to localhost I got this Fatal error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login" in C:\wamp64\www\MDSAP\mdsap-api\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php on line 317
    ( ! ) Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "csrf_provider" under "security.firewalls.main.form_login" in C:\wamp64\www\MDSAP\mdsap-api\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode.php on line 317
```

This is security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADHERANT:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_STAGIAIRE:   ROLE_USER
        ROLE_PARTENAIRE:  ROLE_USER
        ROLE_DUPPLESSIX:  ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            # Add your favorite authentication process here

        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  false # can be omitted as its default value

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY ] }
```

Comment: Correction made on deleting the main section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but all you need to do is to enable csrf protaction before updating composer.

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: true
```